# Rewrite rule for file extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I think I need 2 rules for this ... but I'm not getting there...

How can I redirect these URLs:

(1) http://example.com/myapi/XXXXXXXX

(2) http://example.com/myapi/XXXXXXXX.json

(3) http://example.com/myapi/XXXXXXXX.xml

XXXXXXXX is alpha-numeric string variable length

(1) Goes to normalPage.php?feed=XXXXXXXX

(2) and (3) go to feeds.php?feed=XXXXXXXX&type=json (or xml)

I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^myapi/([^/]+)$ normalPage.php?feed=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^myapi/([^/]+).([^/]+)$ feeds.php?feed=$1&type=$2 [L]
```

Comment: the two RewriteRules in question look correct for what you've described. what is the problem you're seeing? And this is all in your root's .htaccess? Have you cleared browser cache?

Comment: It seems the first rule is always being applied...

Comment: ahh, ok. So may need to either switch the order or modify the first rule to exclude periods from the pattern? something like `RewriteRule ^myapi/([^/.]+)$ normalPage.php?feed=$1 [L]`

Comment: That damn period did the trick :D Also added a period to the second rule as it wasn't passing $2 right! Submit your comment as an answer please

Comment: ah ok. good to see that fixed it. and good catch on the 2nd rule as well. added as answer. thanks

Comment: thanks for the help. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the first rule to exclude periods from the pattern. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^myapi/([^/.]+)$ normalPage.php?feed=$1 [L]
```